# bibtex ignores MACROs in bst style

Tags: macros, bibtex, custom-bib

So I created my custom bst file using "latex makebst" it mostly works fine and I slowly get a rudimentary hang how the .bst thing works. Mostly thanks to this guide
http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf

However, my months are not replaced. For example I want {feb} to be replaced with Feb. Notice the capital F and the dot.

There are entries in the file like
MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

but they seem to be ignored. I also tried some of the journal macro abbreviation but bibtex seems to ignore them too.

PS: Also for example plain.bst defines
MACRO {feb} {"February"}

but
month = {feb},
from the bib database keeps being just "feb"

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: A macro should be used without braces: `month = feb,`

Comment: If I put feb in a field, say I put it in journal, in my .bib file by hand, the macro does not seem to substitute it into June when I compile. Am I getting wrong what a macro is supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros or strings defined with `MACRO` or `@string` are to be used without braces or quotes around them, so

```
month = feb,
```

is the way to use it. The main difference between the two definitions is that `MACRO` is in a `.bst` file, whereas `@string` goes in the `.bib` file.